# How to refresh AKS RBAC role assignment?

Tags: azure, azure-aks, azure-rbac

I depoloyed this rbac manifest to cluster:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: rbac-reader
subjects:
- kind: Group
  name: AKS_READER
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: view
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

Im applying build-in role: view to the AAD group AKS_READER for a whole cluster. I tested it with my team member account. I deleted him from previously set group which had role:
Azure Kubernetes Service Cluster User Role and also deleted him as a Contributor on a cluster and then added him to the new group **AKS_READER**, but when he ran command: `kubectl auth can-i create pods` the output is still 'yes'. Do I need somehow refresh these rights? Does the user needs to run again: `az aks get-credentials ....` ?

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to refresh the AKS RBAC role assignment of the particular user but
> adding the role assignment using the to group and I was able to
> Achieve the required policy assignment successfully.

When you apply a ClusterRoleBinding to a Kubernetes cluster, it binds a set of permissions (in this case, the "view" role) to a particular set of subjects (in this case, the "AKS_READER" group). However, changes to role bindings or group memberships do not automatically take effect for a user's current session.

I tried to change the access of the `user` with member using the role change and trying to revoke as `AKS_RBAC_READER` from the contributor.

[image]

Command to achieve the new permission to be revoked

```
az aks get-credentials --resource-group myResourceGroup --name myAKSCluster
```

This command will create a new kubectl configuration file in the current directory. The new configuration file will contain the RBAC role assignments for the current cluster.

Now check whether the user still accesses the cluster as the permissions recently provoked so wait till the sync process is done.

Now try to access the cluster from the user and check whether they can access the cluster with the following commands.

Here in this case caching can also be the reason for facing the error.

[image]

Once the permissions are revoked this is the error that we got.

This can also be solved by the command

```
az aks get-credentials
```

Now with the user who ever the permission was revoked
try to access the cluster to create the node

```
kubectl auth can-i create pods
```

With the permission of AKS_RBAC_READER alone, you will not be able to make any changes as per the policy

[image]